# Reverse number in python - Recursion

Tags: python, recursion, reverse

I know there are alot like that question, but I want to know depending on my code, what is the bad thing that will not make it work. I dont want to look at answers...

I need to code that if I receive 1357, so I will get 7531.
( No STR ofcourse ).
I tried something like this:

```
def help_reverse_num(num, index):  # 1357  >>>> 7531
    if num == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return (num % 10) * (10 ** index) + help_reverse_num(num // 10, index + 1)

def reverse_num(num):
    return help_reverse_num(num, 0)

print(reverse_num(1357))
```

The problem with this code, I receive 1357 itself.
but if I would have put (index - 1) at the else and index=3 at reverse_num, then the code would work good.
The question is, how do I make it so the index will run the opposite way? that it will start from 3 or something else, depending the length of the number.

Any tip will be welcomed ( no solution please, its a practice for a hard work ).

EDIT:
I have a solution, I made a few months ago ( when I was better ):

```
def reverse_number(n, rem=0):
if n == 0:
    return rem
else:
    ones = n // 10
    second_1 = rem * 10
    second_2 = n % 10
    return reverse_number(ones, second_2 + second_1)
```

But I did not think of it now, so I want to do it by my own idea.

Comment: You're basically asking how to find out how many digits are in `num`. This can be determined from the base 10 logarithm, as you might remember from high school algebra.

Comment: instead of adding your returns, put them into a list and append to it. return the reverse of the list.

Comment: Have the helper report back what `index` needs to be for you to place the digit you stripped off.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: How is that different from making a string of the number and reversing that?

Comment: @ScottHunter You are right, about what you said.
About Barmar, I dont really know what you said, I never learned such thing... 
About scoott, what do you mean? how do I do it? sorry, my english not at its best.

Comment: @Scott  this is clearly a task to be solved with some restrained. STR is not allowed. Using a list, storing the digit and reversing it is not using STR.

Comment: @PatrickArtner yea, but the point is not using list or anything of the sort. it is basically the same, also, it will be a long code if I do it.
That is why I wanted to do without "cheating", its for algorithm practice.
I already have a solution ( EDITED it ), it was half a year ago when I was studying by myself, but now when I returned to python, I am really bad so I didnt think of it, instead, I thought of what I wrote at the start of the post, that is why I want to see if I can progress with that code.